# Sliding Navigation Up & Down JQuery Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation, slidetoggle

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var pull = $('#pull');
    menu = $('nav ul');
    menuHeight = menu.height();

    $('#pull').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle();
    });

    $('.link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle('1200');
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        var w = $(window).width();
        if (w < 600 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
            enter code here
        }
    });
});
</script>

<nav class="clearfix">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li><a href="#home" class="link">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" class="link">How-to</a></li>
        <li><a href="#work" class="link">Icons</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="link">Design</a></li>
    </ul>
<a href="#" id="pull"><img src="images/logo.png"/></a>
</nav>
```

I found this code online from a tutorial, and I have tweaked it a bit to make it what I want the navigation to do.I am having an issue with being able to toggle this menu up and down. I want it to be where I click on the #pull id, that it will toggle down and show me the links. Then, when I click on a link, I want it to toggle back up and hide the links, but I only want it to do that for the responsive aspect of the navigation, not when it is on the normal view of it. It toggles up whether it is responsive or not. PLEASE HELP ME!

Here Is A Link To The Files http://www.mediafire.com/download/cz1q3rg3fqm5pxh/Demo-Files.7z

Comment: menu and menuHeight aren't declared with var.

Comment: @Mark so how do I fix this issue so It runs how I want it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**trigger both responsively**

```
var menu = $('nav ul'), plink = $('#pull, .link'), go;
function acdc() {
    var ww = $(window).width();
    if (ww>600 && go) {//on desktop
        if (menu.is(':hidden')) { menu.removeAttr('style'); }
        plink.unbind();
        go=false;
    } else if (ww<600 && !go) {//on small screen
        plink.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle();
        });
        go=true;
    }
}
acdc();
$(window).resize(function () { acdc(); });
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/Lt9V3/

Comment: I tried using that code in order for it to trigger both responsively and it still didn't work correctly?

Comment: It did not show any errors in the console in Google Chrome. But with that code, will that be able to execute probably in the media queries I have set up, so when I click on the #pull, it will toggle down, and then when I click on one of the five links will it toggle back up? I just want it to do that in the media queries, not the desktop query.

Comment: looks like it needs to be unbound on go, updated answer.

Comment: switched the toggle, so it happens on media and not desktop.

Comment: can you do that in JSfiddle? I am kind of confused right now with how to fix this.. Sorry for being a pain, i'm still a beginner with some of this JQuery sadly..

Comment: The code that you used on Fiddle; I applied it to my source code and it doesn't do what it did in Fiddle? Any reasons why?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/Lt9V3/ It works exactly the same in your Fiddle as in mine, but when I put it in my actually source code it doesn't do anything like it did in Fiddle?